# How to get two variables from a get response in solidity using chainlink

Tags: solidity, chainlink

Let say we have such code, I need to extract two uint256 fields from a get response. With one field it works fine, when I add a second req.add("path", "...") it keeps returning zero. I thought that the problem might be in jobId that doesnt match to this get request, but as I understood, jobId is only responsible for the type was returned.

```
function request() public {
  Chainlink.Request memory req = buildChainlinkRequest('ca98366cc7314957b8c012c72f05aeeb', address(this), this.fulfill.selector);
  req.add(
      'get',
      'https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=ETH&tsyms=USD'
  );
  req.add('path', 'RAW,ETH,USD,VOLUME24HOUR');
  req.addInt('times', 10**18); // Multiply by times value to remove decimals. Parameter required so pass '1' if the number returned doesn't have decimals
  sendChainlinkRequest(req, (1 * LINK_DIVISIBILITY) / 10); // 0,1*10**18 LINK
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Job ID specific which jobs will handle the request -- if the JobID does not handle multi variable responses then, then it wont work.

Also your request seems to return only one value? The value of VOLUME24HOUR?

to do multiple variable responses follow the guide here:
https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/multi-variable-responses

Your code looks more like single "word" responses as documented here
https://docs.chain.link/any-api/get-request/examples/single-word-response

which is not the right approach.

note the job ID is different from single and multi word responses. You can find job IDs and community jobs here:
https://docs.chain.link/any-api/find-oracle/